# Can anybody explain how the receiver know if two nonconsecutive TCP segments belong to the same packet?

Tags: tcp

Can anybody explain how does the receiver know if two nonconsecutive TCP segments belong to the same or different packets ? And how does it know if the next segment is the last segments in the packet ?

Answer (score 2):

The receiver doesn't assemble TCP segments into packets, it assembles them into streams. The receiver knows the location, in the stream, of its received segment by its sequence number.

Is it possible that you are expecting the count result of the receiving application's `read()` system call to conform to the sending application's `write()` system call? If so, you will be disappointed. TCP streams are byte-wise, not packet-wise, streams. They neither preserve nor honor the boundaries of the sending system calls.

Answer (score 1):

TCP does not deal with fragmentation. That's an IP problem. Packets arrive at the TCP level only when complete. IP uses special fields in the header that indicates whether the packet is fragmented or not, and, if yes, whether the fragment received is the last one or not.

You may take a look :
[Transmission Control Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)
[Internet Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but from the link you added "TCP takes care of keeping track of the individual units of data transmission, called segments, that a message is divided into for efficient routing through the network."

Comment: Yes, but that's another problem (if that was what you were asking for then I misunderstood your question). That means that a message is not send as it is, but is divided in packets. The size of a packet depend on MSS/MTU. TCP uses a special field in the header ("sequence number") to sort received packets and manage nonconsecutive packets.